# Custom bone shapes missing after using the symmetrize operator

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

I encounter an issue when symmetrizing the Edit bones through the operator
`bpy.ops.armature.symmetrize(direction='POSITIVE_X')`

The operator copies the widgets from the left to the right side (e.g. the bone **nose.R.001** has the widget **WGT-rig_nose.L.002** instead of **WGT-rig_nose.R.002** after the operation).

The shapes are missing completely after saving and reloading once. Is there a way to keep the custom shapes without using a custom script? Thank you very much!

[image: rigify widgets]